# android saving to SD card

Tags: android, image, save, sd-card

hi to all i have a small problem

i have this code to save an image to an SD card

```
public String SDSave( ) { //View arg0
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                OutputStream outStream = null;
                File file = new File( extStorageDirectory , AdName + ".PNG");
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();

                    Toast.makeText(WhereAmI.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(WhereAmI.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(WhereAmI.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

and im calling it from another methode like this:

```
String sdSave = SDSave(extStorageDirectory + "/qr11.PNG");
```

and im showing 2 errors the first is at the method at `public String SDSave( )`  and it says:

```
This method must return a result of type String
```

and the second is at `String sdSave = SDSave(extStorageDirectory + "/qr11.PNG");` and it says:

```
The method SDSave() in the type WhereAmI is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

some help please on how to fix it.....

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You declared your method as `public String` which means it has to return a String object from the function (using the `return` keyword) if you don't want the function to return anything, use the `void` keyword instead of `String`.

The second error means that somewhere you called `SDSave` method using a String as arguments (`SDSave(extStorageDirectory + "/qr11.PNG");`) while this function takes no arguments (`public String SDSave( )`).

I suggest you would try a [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167179/java-tutorial), since those rules are the very basics of Java (and actually, of many programing languages).

Answer (score 1):

Your asking your method to return a String

```
 public String SDSave()
```

you would need the line, at the end of your code:

```
return "someString";
```

If you don't want to return a string use:

```
public void SDSave()
```

The second error, your trying to pass a String into your method, but your method doesn't take any variables. You would need:

```
public void SDSave(String myInputStringVariable)
```

Yes these are Java basic's , so I'd go read up on Java and OO, also check this out:

[Top Ten Errors Java Programmers Make](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html)

Answer (score 1):

try writing this line in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope it will help u.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SDSave(String file){
    File f=new File(file);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use my sample code shared on Github repo [link](https://github.com/VishnuGShephertz/Image-Sharing-Saving-and-Caching-in-Android-) This sample contains :

1. Download image from web.
2. You can also share this image.
3. You can save this image on Sd card.
4. Image Caching is also there