# How to store images in Cache Memory

Tags: android, caching

I am totally blank on this. I want to download the images from a Url and have to store it internally so that next time I need not connect to web and instead retrieve it from cache memory. But I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone help me with a code snippet.

Comment: Have you tried famous Fedors code

Comment: Sorry! What are you referring to?

Comment: I am taliking about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: @Android_Selva ya saurabh is right about to use this example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class CacheStore {
    private static CacheStore INSTANCE = null;
    private HashMap<String, String> cacheMap;
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmapMap;
    private static final String cacheDir = "/Android/data/com.yourbusiness/cache/";
    private static final String CACHE_FILENAME = ".cache";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private CacheStore() {
        cacheMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        bitmapMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
        File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),cacheDir);
        if(!fullCacheDir.exists()) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Directory doesn't exist");
            cleanCacheStart();
            return;
        }
        try {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), CACHE_FILENAME))));
            cacheMap = (HashMap<String,String>)is.readObject();
            is.close();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Corrupted stream");
            cleanCacheStart();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "File not found");
            cleanCacheStart();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Input/Output error");
            cleanCacheStart();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Class not found");
            cleanCacheStart();
        }
    }

    private void cleanCacheStart() {
        cacheMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),cacheDir);
        fullCacheDir.mkdirs();
        File noMedia = new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), ".nomedia");
        try {
            noMedia.createNewFile();
            Log.i("CACHE", "Cache created");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Couldn't create .nomedia file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized static void createInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new CacheStore();
        }
    }

    public static CacheStore getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) createInstance();
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void saveCacheFile(String cacheUri, Bitmap image) {
        File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),cacheDir);
        String fileLocalName = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyhhmmssSSS").format(new java.util.Date())+".PNG";
        File fileUri = new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), fileLocalName);
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(fileUri);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            cacheMap.put(cacheUri, fileLocalName);
            Log.i("CACHE", "Saved file "+cacheUri+" (which is now "+fileUri.toString()+") correctly");
            bitmapMap.put(cacheUri, image);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), CACHE_FILENAME))));
            os.writeObject(cacheMap);
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Error: File "+cacheUri+" was not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("CACHE", "Error: File could not be stuffed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getCacheFile(String cacheUri) {
        if(bitmapMap.containsKey(cacheUri)) return (Bitmap)bitmapMap.get(cacheUri);

        if(!cacheMap.containsKey(cacheUri)) return null;
        String fileLocalName = cacheMap.get(cacheUri).toString();
        File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),cacheDir);
        File fileUri = new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), fileLocalName);
        if(!fileUri.exists()) return null;

        Log.i("CACHE", "File "+cacheUri+" has been found in the Cache");
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.toString());
        bitmapMap.put(cacheUri, bm);
        return bm;
    }
}
```

Comment: to store in sd card http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530737/android-saving-to-sd-card

Comment: link is gone now

Answer (score 2):

Although the selected answer is correct, but it's a bit lengthy as its downloading image from the server first. Those who are just looking at how to save bitmap into cache for them we can use Android's native LruCache library. Here I have written a detailed article on the topic [LruCache in Java](https://handyopinion.com/how-to-save-and-load-image-from-cache-using-lrucache-in-java-android/) & [LruCache in Kotlin](https://handyopinion.com/how-to-save-and-load-image-from-cache-using-lrucache-in-kotlin-android/).

Java Class to save Bitmap in Cache:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import androidx.collection.LruCache;

public class MyCache {

    private static MyCache instance;
    private LruCache<Object, Object> lru;

    private MyCache() {

        lru = new LruCache<Object, Object>(1024);

    }

    public static MyCache getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyCache();
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public LruCache<Object, Object> getLru() {
        return lru;
    }

    public void saveBitmapToCahche(String key, Bitmap bitmap){

        try {
            MyCache.getInstance().getLru().put(key, bitmap);
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public Bitmap retrieveBitmapFromCache(String key){

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) MyCache.getInstance().getLru().get(key);
            return bitmap;
        }catch (Exception e){}
        return null;
    }

}
```