# How to store downloaded images in cache

Tags: java, android, image

I'm working on a Syllabus application for my project in Android which shows a list of subjects in a `RecyclerView`. When clicked on a subject, it downloads the image from its URL and displays it in the `ImageView`. I need a code which stores the Image in cache once it is downloaded, so the user doesn't need to download the image from the URL again and again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store images in Cache Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580418/how-to-store-images-in-cache-memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have many images to load in your app i offer to use external storage instead of cache 
because if your app cache filled up android deletes all applications caches

Answer (score 2):

For downloading images, you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library. This library lets you download the image efficiently and cache them also so you don't have to manually do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso library.
Reference - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library